# My sprite has a weird white pixelated border around it

Tags: python, animation, sprite

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

white=(255,255,255)
black=(0,0,0)
green=(0,255,0)
pygame.init()
window=pygame.display.set_mode((740, 450),0,32)
image=pygame.image.load("Rogue.png")
image.set_colorkey(white)

x,y=0,0
movex,movey=0,0

while True:
    window.fill(green)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_LEFT:
                movex+=-1
            elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                movex+=1
            elif event.key==K_UP:
                movey+=-1
            elif event.key==K_DOWN:
                movey+=1
    x=movex
    y=movey

    window.blit(image,(x,y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Every time I run the code my character has an ugly white aura-esque sort of thing going on...
If you could try it out and tell me what is wrong that would be stellar! :D
Here is the Png: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xNzp.jpg
And screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH3Vj.jpg

Comment: Can you include a screenshot so we can see the problem at hand? And perhaps upload the PNG as went so we can see what it should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem. The transparent parts of your image are *transparent white*; that is, the RGBA values are near (1, 1, 1, 0). The pixels on the border of your opaque region are partially transparent and thus are blended with transparent white. This is why you see the white haze around the border of your sprite.

There are two ways to solve your problem.

## Outside of Code

This problem is better fixed outside of code. In whatever graphics tool you are using, you need to make the partially-transparent portions of the image use RGB values that match the nearby opaque pixels of your sprite. Depending on the tool, there may be a built-in operation for exactly this purpose.

## Post-Process Your Sprite

For each pixel (X,Y) in your sprite:

Let (R,G,B,A) be the color of your pixel. If I will assume these are floats in the range [0,1]. The current color (R,G,B) is wrong, because it has been blended with white according to the alpha A of the pixel. That is, if (R',G',B') is the correct color, you have

(R,G,B) = A * (1,1,1) + (1 - A) * (R',G',B').

Solving for (R',G',B') you get

(R',G',B') = ((R,G,B) - (A,A,A)) / (1 - A).

Thus you can fix your color components by using the following.

```
R = (R - A) / (1 - A)
G = (G - A) / (1 - A)
B = (B - A) / (1 - A)
```

Comment: Ok thank you I will try to edit it with Gimp. I'm not sure if I will be able to but I'll get back to you

Comment: @Dominico909 Zoom in and click on individual pixels with the color picker tool. This lets you inspect the RGBA values.

Comment: @ Timothy But then what do I do from there?

Comment: @Dominico909 I have a solution for you to post process your image with code. Updating the answer in a moment.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm still relatively new to python, could you show me how to implement it in my code?

Comment: @Dominico909 If your color components are integers between 0 and 255, the updates look like the following instead: `R = 255 * (R - A) / (255 - A)`.

Comment: @Dominico909 I can't help you with that since it's so basic. Look at the documentation for the image class you're using. This answer gives you two working solutions...